# Plugin recommendation needed: expiring links

Tags: plugins

I am looking for plugins like Unique Links, One-Time Link Generator, and WP-OneTime-Link (which was recommended to me) but I can not find any of those – not even when I use an internet search

I am sure there is a good reason for it – but I still need the function.

I want to create a link that is only valid for a certain time (or clicks) and then get into a different page (error or link no longer valid page) . I don't want people to copy & paste links to free content via email without filling out a survey before.

Please advise with any help!

I have no understanding of coding - and it does not need to be Fort Knox safe it should just avoid copying and pasting a URL. I use Everest Forms for my survey and and the end of the survey I can send them to a page - so the redirect:to URL needs to be a URL that I simply can type in but still would do what is needed - obviously i can not change the ULR after each survey enter lol

best, M

PS Something like pretty links would not work – yes they have an option for expiring links – but it is a static link. I need a link that can be created by a shortcode (or something) simply from a survey that sends the user to a different page on my site where they can get stuff (not a download!) to read. ANY help is so much appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to WPSE. Plugin recommendations or discussions on third-party plugins are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.